# Boost noncopyable is private error

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

To start with, I have this exact same code working on my Windows machine, and I don't use linux too much so it may be a problem with how I am trying to compile it. I would appreciate any help in figuring out the error that I am getting as I am not sure what is causing it, and going through the file tree leads back to io_service.hpp, something that shouldn't have a problem (if I am doing it right).

```
g++ -L/usr/include/ -lboost_regex Source.cpp -o source
```

My client.cpp code

```
#include "client.h"

std::string port = "13";            /* Destination port. */

void client::write()
{
    using namespace std; // For strlen.
    std::cout << "Enter message: ";
    char request[max_length];
    std::cin.getline(request, max_length);
    size_t request_length = strlen(request);
    boost::asio::write(*s, boost::asio::buffer(request, request_length));
}

void client::send(char c[])
{
    boost::asio::write(*s, boost::asio::buffer(c, max_length));
}

// This will be used by the edge nodes to connect to the server
client::client(void)
{
    tcp::resolver resolver(io);
    tcp::resolver::query query(tcp::v4(), "ALERT-Core-0", port);
    tcp::resolver::iterator iterator = resolver.resolve(query);

    s = new tcp::socket(io);
    s->connect(*iterator);
}
```

Client.h

```
#pragma once
#include <boost\asio.hpp>
#include <boost\thread.hpp>

using namespace boost::asio::ip;

class client
{
public:
    client(void);
    ~client(void) { }
    void write();
    void send(char c[]);

private:
    boost::asio::io_service io;
    tcp::socket* s;
    static const size_t max_length = 1024;
};
```

My main function initializes it by calling

```
client c = client();
while(s[0] != '1')
{
    c.send(s);
    memset(&s, '\0', 1024);
    std::cin.getline(s, 1024);
}
```

My output from terminal is:

```
In file included from /usr/include/boost/asio/basic_io_object.hpp:20:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/asio/basic_socket.hpp:24,
                 from /usr/include/boost/asio/basic_datagram_socket.hpp:25,
                 from /usr/include/boost/asio.hpp:20,
                 from Client.h:2,
                 from Source.cpp:1:
/usr/include/boost/noncopyable.hpp: In copy constructor ‘boost::asio::io_service::io_service(const boost::asio::io_service&)’:
/usr/include/boost/noncopyable.hpp:27:7: error: ‘boost::noncopyable_::noncopyable::noncopyable(const boost::noncopyable_::noncopyable&)’ is private
/usr/include/boost/asio/io_service.hpp:179:1: error: within this context
In file included from Source.cpp:1:0:
Client.h: In copy constructor ‘client::client(const client&)’:
Client.h:11:1: note: synthesized method ‘boost::asio::io_service::io_service(const boost::asio::io_service&)’ first required here
Source.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
Source.cpp:5:20: note: synthesized method ‘client::client(const client&)’ first required here
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are invoking your class's default copy constructor with the line `client c = client();` which is in turn trying to copy the `io` member of your class, but `io_service` is marked noncopyable, so it's failing. You can fix it by changing your code to simply `client c;`.

Since your class has noncopyable members, you should yourself make your copy constructor (and copy assignment operator) private to make the failure more obvious.

As for the reason it is not failing on some compilers, it's possible that whatever compiler you're using on Windows can see that `client c = client();` is really semantically the same as `client c;` and is making the change for you, but I don't know if that's required or even allowed by the standard (or a good idea for that matter).

Comment: That solved it, thanks so much. Will close when it allows me. Just for understanding, does this not happen in Windows, or is it handled differently?

Comment: See my last edit for my suggestion as to why it works in Windows. My feeling is that the inconsistency is either a bug or platform dependent behaviour on the part of one or both of the compilers.

Comment: @penguin what compiler do you use on Windows?

Comment: @IgorR. I am using the Visual Studio C++ 2012 compiler. Currently compiling with the x64 compiler, with the x64 version of boost as well (on Windows).